# Removing characters between |pipes|

Tags: text-processing

I have various text files I need to modify

```
test.xyz|test3.abc|test5232.lop|filename.test|file.text|qwerty.bat|...
```

I'm trying to automate the process of removing "test5232.lop", including the proceeding the pipe, like this:

```
test.xyz|test3.abc|filename.test|file.text|qwerty.bat|...
```

Without the need to generate a temp file if possible

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

This looks like a job for `cut`.  Tell it the delimiter is `|`, that we want to specify fields to drop, not fields to keep (`--complement`) and that the we want to select field 3 (to drop in this case).

**Code:**

```
 cut -d '|' --complement -f 3
```

**Test:**

```
$ echo 'test.xyz|test3.abc|test5232.lop|filename.test|file.text|qwerty.bat|x' | cut -d '|' --complement -f 3
test.xyz|test3.abc|filename.test|file.text|qwerty.bat|x
```

Comment: Nice!  I mostly use [POSIX features only](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cut.html), so I wasn't aware of the `--complement` option.  Notably, this is GNU-specific.

Comment: I was looking at a more specific option, because its in text file and "test5232.lop" isn't always in the same place.

Comment: @JohnDoe6262, that's actually a much less interesting use case.

Comment: @JohnDoe6262, maybe @wildcard will modify his `sed` answer, because if just want to remove a specific string `sed` is super easy.

Comment: If your `cut` doesn't support `--complement` you can use a field list instead: `cut -d '|' -f 1-2,4-`

Answer (score 2):

Just use Sed:

```
sed 's/|test5232\.lop//' file.txt
```

---

Original answer, before request was clarified:

### POSIX features only, using [Sed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html):

```
sed 's/|[^|]*//2' file.txt
```

If you know that all lines have at least three `|` symbols, you can use the more intuitive form:

```
sed 's/[^|]*|//3' file.txt
```

Comment: This works well, can sed input/output to the same filename without needing to create a temp filename?

Comment: Not portably.  Use `-i` option if your Sed supports it.  (Check the man page for whether it requires an argument or not; that depends on what implementation you use.)

Answer (score 2):

To replace the 3rd field (where a "field" is "anything except a pipe, zero or more times, followed by a pipe") with nothing:

```
awk '{$0=gensub(/[^|]*\|/, "", 3); print $0}' input
```

Apparently you want to remove "test5232.lop" anywhere in the line:

```
sed -i 's/|test5232\.lop//' input
```

(although any solution, including `sed -i` creates a temporary file)

Comment: gnu `ed` does not create a temporary file. https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html
It can be obtuse to use, but when it comes to things like editing files in directories you can't execute, it's better to be obtuse and functional ^-^

Answer (score 2):

Check also this awk simple solution. Will remove the string no matter where it is and should be portable:

```
$ a="test.xyz|test3.abc|test5232.lop|filename.test|file.text|qwerty.bat"
$ awk -F"test5232.lop." '{printf("%s%s\n",$1,$2)}' <<<"$a"
test.xyz|test3.abc|filename.test|file.text|qwerty.bat
```

About your request for in-place editing , GNU AWK version > 4.1 also can make inplace edits according [to gawk manual:](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Extension-Sample-Inplace)

```
awk -i inplace -v INPLACE_SUFFIX=.bak '{...}'
```

But in any case, neither awk nor sed nor perl can achieve a real inplace editing. GNU `sed` Info Pages clarify this issue for us:

```
'-i[SUFFIX]'
'--in-place[=SUFFIX]'
     This option specifies that files are to be edited in-place.  GNU
     'sed' does this by creating a temporary file and sending output to
     this file rather than to the standard output.(1).
```

Meaning that you can use any solution in-here by appending at the end something like this:

```
awk/sed/perl/whatever oldfile >tmpfile && mvtmpfile oldfile && rm -f tmpfile
```

Comment: @JohnDoe6262 Clarification about in-place editing added

Comment: To be fair... `ed`, rather than `sed` can be used in-place, it's just... far more obtuse to use (must consult manual a lot), unless you actually take some time to run it interactively to figure out how the heck it works. https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -F'[|]' -pale '$_ = join "|", grep $_ ne "test5232.lop", @F' yourfile

perl -F'[|]' -pale '1 while s/(^|\|)\Ktest5232\.lop(\||$)//g'     yourfile

sed -e '
  :clip
     s/[|]test5232\.lop[|]/|/
   tclip

   s/^test5232\.lop[|]//
   s/[|]test5232\.lop$//
   s/^test5232\.lop$//
' yourfile
```